# I don't understand what the debug explains

Tags: python

I have made a small program to learn the basis, and I don't understand why it doesn't workso could you help me by explaining my mistake.
Every answers are welcome

```
import random
def gessing_game():
 t = 0
 r = random.randint(0,100)
 print(r)
 y = int(input("Please choose your number"))
 while  y != r:
  t = t + 1
  print("You have made",t,"attempts")
    if y > r:
     print("Too big!")
     y = int(input(print("Please try again")))
    if y < r:
     print("Too small!")
     y = int(input(print("Please try again")))
    if y == r:
     print("Well done you found it")
gessing_game()
```

here is how they define my mistake

```
File "U:\Documents\Exo sur Thonny\Guessing_game.py", line 10
    if y > r:
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. Use a set number of spaces (4 or 8), or use tabs. Your editor can help you with this.

Comment: The `if` statements should be indented with the exact same number of spaces as the preceeding `print("You have made",t,"attempts")` line.

Comment: DONT use tabs. Uses 4 spaces. Always. That's the standard.

Comment: "I don't understand what the debug explains" - well, do you know what the word `Indentation` means? Do you understand how code should be indented in Python? What exactly caused the confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python syntax is based on indentations.I'm also at basic level of python programming.it's simply telling you that **you didn't need to add any indentation behind your "if"**.When you add an indentation you simply open a block.

Comment: ok thanks a lot to you all you all helped me my problem seems solved